# How do I delete an entire row if a cell in the row contains an error?

Tags: excel, vba

```
On Error Resume Next
Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

Range("A6").Select
```

This is what I have. I was working fine.

The problem is when the columns C does not have errors, it keeps showing an error message saying it can't fine the error type.

It works fine when there are errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Maybe an if statement?

Thanks guys

Comment: are you sure the error is thrown on the line you delete the row and not after? have a look here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20353-no-cells-were-found.html- Perhaps you can use the `If Err <> 0 Then` right after then `.Delete` Statement?

Comment: this is the very end of my code. When I separately run it, it works fine but when it's combined to the rest of the code it shows an error message.. Very frustrating. anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Range("C:C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        r.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

If it does not work and you still see an error message, then error handling must be enabled.  From the VBE window menu:

**Tools** > **Options...** > **General** > and make sure **Break on Unhandled Errors** is checked.

Comment: If you STILL see the error message, in the VBE window:  Tools > Options... > General > mark sure Break on Unhandled errors  is checked

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks, I am looking for a way to have the macro itself establish the configuration.